# Using an environment variable in an rsync argument (dealing with quotes and escape character)

Tags: linux, bash, environment-variables

I want to use rsync with an --exclude command that looks like

```
rsync -av --exclude={"*.ext1","*.ext2", "*.ext3"} source target
```

(For some reason it is more handy to me to use such a syntax than using the --exclude-from=FILE syntax)

I would like to use an environement variable with rsync so that I could do

```
export toto='{"*.ext1","*.ext2", "*.ext3"}'
rsync -av --exclude=$toto source target
```

The problem is that it doesn't work the way I wish. When I use the automatic completion over the $toto variable it shows :

```
\{\"\*.ext1\",\"\*.ext2\",\ \"\*.ext3\"\}
```

It is actually what rsync understands and it gets totally confused.

Could anybody **explain the rational behind this "quotes and escape characters" behavior?**

Comment: Are you wanting to use your shell's brace expansion to expand `{}`, or do you want to pass the literal string `{"*.ext1","*.ext2", "*.ext3"}` to rsync?

Comment: I'm not sure to fully understand what you mean by _shell's brace expansion to expand {}_  I want rsync to exactly receive `{"*.ext1","*.ext2", "*.ext3"}`

Comment: I don't think rsync recognizes that syntax.  But, if you remove the space after the second comma, bash will use brace expansion to expand `--exclude={"*.ext1","*.ext2","*.ext3"}` to the strings `--exclude=*.ext1 --exclude=*.ext2 --exclude=*.ext3` and pass those  3 arguments to rsync.  I'm pretty sure that is what you want.

Comment: Syntax  `--exclude={"*.ext1","*.ext2","*.ext3"}` do work with rsync as well as `--exclude=*.ext1 --exclude=*.ext2 --exclude=*.ext3`. I just don't understand why I can't use an environnement variable in this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works:

```
MYEXCLUDE={'*.ext1','*.ext2'}
eval rsync -av --exclude=$MYEXCLUDE src dest
```

As already mentioned, `{,}` triggers brace expansion (btw, the space before ext3 in your example **is** a problem: it prevents brace exp). 
And rsync's exclude option only accepts a single pattern (this means that everything can be understood by replacing rsync and echo).

By chance, when the 1st line sets the variable, brace expansion does not yet take place (`echo $MYEXCLUDE` shows :  `{*.ext1,*.ext2}`). 
And brace expansion happens **after** variable expansion. So the trick is to use `eval` to have the expansion just-in-time. To fully understand, compare the following 2 lines:

```
MYEXCLUDE=--exclude={'*.ext1','*.ext2'}
echo $MYEXCLUDE
eval echo $MYEXCLUDE
```

displays

```
--exclude={*.ext1,*.ext2}
--exclude=*.ext1 --exclude=*.ext2
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question, you *cannot* use *brace expansion* in the content of the environment variable.

Why? *Brace Expansion* is provided by your shell (bash). When `rsync` *reads* the content of `--exclude=$toto` no shell expansions are applied. A better approach would be to generate the list of files to exclude, redirect the output to a file and `--exlcude-from=file` where `file` would contain a single filename (or rule) on each line.

All of the quoting and escaping that is applied is from the attempt by `rsync` to make valid Unix filenames or patterns from `{"*.ext1","*.ext2","*.ext3"}`. (basically you have confused the heck out of `rsync` and it is doing its best with the mess you have given it).

When you have what should be a *brace expansion* stored in a variable, no shell expansions will be applied, quotes lose their meaning and `rsync` is left trying to sort out the mess.

Look at the `--exclude`, `--exclude-from` and `--filter` in [rsync(1) - Linux manual page](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/rsync.1.html)

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. It is clear to me why this didn't work.